# Button created with JavaScript, when the button is created again the on click event happens twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, modal-dialog

I have a popup (modal), the data on the modal is generated with JavaScript. An ajax request is sent to get the data that is displayed

[image: modal with data]

when the enable or disable button is clicked, an ajax is sent with this info to to the back-end.

The problem I am having is when the modal closed and then reopened the click action happens twice (if you click on the enable it send the message the amount of times the popup was opened and closed).

This is some of the code that create the modal

```
$(document).on('click', '.availability', function() {
    $('.availability_modal_table_body').empty();
    var stuff = $(this).data('info').split(',');

    $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: base_url+"catalogs/"+stuff[0]+"/options",
           
            success: function(data) {
                $('.availability_modal_title').text(`Options for ${stuff[1]}`);

                    var string ="";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.avalable.length; i++) {
               string+=`<tr class="option_${data.avalable[i].id}"><td>${data.avalable[i].name}</td><td>`;
  
                    if(data.avalable[i].catalog_id == null){
                        string+= `<button  data-toggle='tooltip' class='btn  btn-info' data-original-title='View'>Create Add</button> `;
                        string+= `<button value="ad_block"${stuff[0]}  class='btn ad_disable btn-warning' data-info="${data.avalable[i].id},${stuff[0]}">Block</button>`;
                    }else if(data.avalable[i].order_id == null){
                             string+= `<button value="create_ad"${stuff[0]}  data-toggle='tooltip' class='btn  btn-info view' data-original-title='View'>Create Add</button> `;
                             string+= `<button value="enable_Ad"${stuff[0]}  class='btn enable_ad btn-warning' data-info="${data.avalable[i].item_id}">Enable</button>`;

                    }else{
                         string+= `<button value="create_ad"${stuff[0]}  data-toggle='tooltip' class='btn  btn-success view' data-original-title='View'>View Booking</button>`;

                    }
                    string+="</td></tr>";
                }
                $('.availability_modal_table_body').html(string);                
                $('#availability_modal').modal('show');
                 
            }
        });
```

This is the Block button code

```
$(document).on('click', '.ad_disable', function() {
       var stuff = $(this).data('info').split(',');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: base_url+`items/block/${stuff[0]}/${stuff[1]}`,
             headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 1){
                      toastr.success('Item blocked');
                      $(this).hide();
                }else{
                    toastr.warning('Failed - See errors');
                }
            }
        });  
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you close the modal you are not unbinding the click event registered to the buttons.

Before closing the modal you should first unbinding click events.

if you using **jQuery ≥ 1.7** then you can unbind clicks like below.

```
$(document).off('click', '.availability')
```

And for **jQuery < 1.7**

```
 $(document).unbind('click', '.availability')
```

For more reference see this artical: https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Thanks , this worked for me 
 $('#availability_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
     $(document).off('click', '.ad_disable');
     $(document).off('click', '.enable_ad');

});